# The return type 'ListView' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context.dartreturn_of_invalid_type_from_closure

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

```
BlocBuilder<RateFetchCubit, RateFetchState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is RateFetchInitial) {
              return const SpinKitFadingCircle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                size: 50.0,
              );
            } else if (state is MarketListed) {
              state.channel.stream.listen((event) {
                var dataList = Market.fromJson(jsonDecode(event.toString())
                    as Map<String, Iterable<dynamic>>);
                print(event.toString());

                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return  const Text("");
                });              });
              }
            }
            return Container();
          },
        )
```

I am getting

> The return type 'ListView' isn't a 'void', as required by the
> closure's context.dartreturn_of_invalid_type_from_closure

Comment: That's because you are returning the `ListView.builder` inside the `state.channel.stream.listen`
also it is not a good practice to listen to stream in the build method because you might add a listener more than once which probably will produce some bugs and definitely will give performance issues

Comment: you returned listview to `.listen(event)` which is a `void function(event)`, you should return it into builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake: Your `ListView.builder` is inside the `state.channel.stream.listen` get it out

Now

```
|_ state.channel.streaam.listen
   |_ return Listview.builder
```

Change it to

```
|_ state.channel.streaam.listen
|_ return Listview.builder
```

Code:

```
          state.channel.stream.listen((event) {
            var dataList = Market.fromJson(jsonDecode(event.toString())
                as Map<String, Iterable<dynamic>>);
            print(event.toString());
                  // It was here 
          }
             return ListView.builder(             //  It should be here
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return  const Text("");
            });              });
        }
```